# Java Print string of doubles to .txt file using formatter

Tags: java, string, double, formatter

I am processing a text file (inputFile) to read several columns of data and print these data to lines in a new text file (columns become rows). These columns of data contain a string of 21 unique doubles.

Checking the process, for example: System.out.println(H2OIN); shows that all of the data are being read into the five arrays properly, however the formatter is only printing the last double in the string to the new text file, i.e:

"450.6

1399.9

121.0

515.8

915.0"

How can I print all of the 21 doubles in the string to the new text file?

Here is my code:

```
public void findFile () throws Exception{

    try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("    0.000")) break;
        }
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stream = line.split(parse);
            start = line.substring(6,9);

            if(start.equals("000")){

                H2OIN = Double.parseDouble(stream[7]);
                CO2IN = Double.parseDouble(stream[8]);
                OILOUT = Double.parseDouble(stream[9]);
                H2OOUT = Double.parseDouble(stream[10]);
                CO2OUT = Double.parseDouble(stream[12]);
                System.out.println(H2OIN);

                f = new Formatter("M:\\TESTPACK\\AL6000803OUT.TXT");

                f.format("SELECT * FROM %s%n", H2OIN);
                f.format("%s%n", CO2IN);
                f.format("%s%n", OILOUT);
                f.format("%s%n", H2OOUT);
                f.format("%s%n", CO2OUT);

                f.close();
            }
        } 
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }            
}
```

}

EDIT- Formatting is a nightmare for what I'm working with, and I can't post images yet. So I will describe it

Year[   ]heading 2[   ]heading 3[   ]...heading 8 etc...

Year[   ]heading 2[   ]heading 3[   ]...H2OIN etc...

0.000[   ]0.000[   ]0.000[   ]0.000

1.000[   ]1.000[   ]15.106[   ]18.89

2.000[   ]4.000[   ]21.911[   ]45.12

...

21.000[   ]4.000[   ]21.911[   ]**450.6**

Comment: Where are these 21 doubles that come from the input file?

Comment: Post an example of your input file

Comment: Difficult to transfer the file I am working with, but it is a text file with two heading lines. The data are indexed by "year", which is the first column of data. I am retrieving columns 7, 8, 9, 10, and 12 from the text file. They happen to have 21 years worth of data that I would like to print to another text file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you have only 5 values in file. I think that issue here: `f = new Formatter("M:\\TESTPACK\\AL6000803OUT.TXT");`
As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.io.File) 
file - The file to use as the destination of this formatter. **If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.
So as I understand you just need to do:

```
public void findFile () throws Exception{

    try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
        f = new Formatter("M:\\TESTPACK\\AL6000803OUT.TXT");
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("    0.000")) break;
        }
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stream = line.split(parse);
            start = line.substring(6,9);

            if(start.equals("000")){

                H2OIN = Double.parseDouble(stream[7]);
                CO2IN = Double.parseDouble(stream[8]);
                OILOUT = Double.parseDouble(stream[9]);
                H2OOUT = Double.parseDouble(stream[10]);
                CO2OUT = Double.parseDouble(stream[12]);
                System.out.println(H2OIN);



                f.format("SELECT * FROM %s%n", H2OIN);
                f.format("%s%n", CO2IN);
                f.format("%s%n", OILOUT);
                f.format("%s%n", H2OOUT);
                f.format("%s%n", CO2OUT);


            }
        }
        f.close();      
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }            
}
```

And as for me it's better if you will use finally clause for closing all resources.

Comment: Actually best is to use try with resource as of Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Doing so returned an error: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.FormatterClosedException"

Comment: It's strange. Attempting to invoke any methods except ioException() in this formatter after it has been closed will result in a FormatterClosedException. So you close formater somewhere...

Comment: I closed the formatter after the try/catch, which seemed to fix it half way. However now the strings print in one long vertical column. Seems to be an issue with the formatting...

Comment: If you want horizontal formatting change "%s%n" to "%s " cause n - the platform-specific line separator as returned by System.getProperty("line.separator").

Comment: I have changed the formatting to "%s ", which prints to rows, however the data for the five strings is printed in sequential order in one long row. Any suggestions for how to print ALL of stream 7 on one row, then all of stream 8 on the second row, etc?